# model include, must belong to 2 other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is really bugging me - cannot seem to get the associations set up correct with includes and so fort. Here are the models in question:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subcategories
 has_many :locations, :through => :subcategories
end
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subcategories
 has_many :category, :through => :subcategories
end
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :location
end
```

I need to output in following structure:

```
Category.name
 Location.name
  Subcategory.name
  Subcategory.name
  Subcategory.name
       (subcategory from another sub category)
```

Controller:

```
 class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @categories = Category.all(:include => [:locations => :subcategories], :group
      =>"subcategories.name")
    end
```

View:

```
 <div class="categorylist">
  <ul>
     <%= @categories.each do |category|%>
    <h3>
        <%=h link_to category.name, category %>
    </h3>
    <%= category.locations.each do |location|%>
    <h6>
        <%= link_to location.name, location %>
    </h6>
        <%= location.subcategories.each do |subcategory|%>
        <p>
        <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory%>
        </p>
        <% end %>   
    <% end %>
   <% end %>    
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

what I want is:

```
 Fruit
  France
    apple
      granny smith
    fig
  India
    pineapple
    banana
 Meat
   India 
     cow
     chicken
     -------------
What I am currently getting:
Fruit
  India
    cow 
    chicken
    banana
    pineapple
```

Meaning I am getting the subcategories based solely on the location and not on location and category..

My problem arises, when i reach the subcategories level, where subcategories should depend on both category and location - They only ever seem to belong to only 1 of the other models, but in my case they must belong to both. I can't seem to get this right. I have tried numerous ways to do this and not sure im even going about it correctly.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance 
Christian

Comment: `They only ever seem to belong to only 1 of the other models, but in my case they must belong to both.` => can you be specific about what is going wrong? I don't see what you mean when you say they "only ever seem to belong to 1 of the other models".

Comment: That when printing the subcategories, they print only depending on the locations, they are not associated to the category... I believe it is going wrong in my include.

Comment: If they are not associated with the category, that means that that association was never created. The creation of the association (between subcategory and category) happens outside of the controller code that you have posted here, so there's no way to help you from what you have provided.

Comment: I don't know what more I can provide?? My :include in the controller is supposed to load these associations with a single query - So that i can print each category, with its subcategories based on locations.

Comment: The problem is (as far as I can tell) this is not a problem of presentation, it's a problem of what's actually in the DB, which is outside of the scope of what you have posted.

Comment: DB: categories has a name and id / locations has a name and id / subcategories has: name, id, category_id, location_id, subcategory_id

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have something like

```
#Category
Fruit
 Apple
 Banana
Vegetable
 Lettuce

#Location
France
 Apple
 Lettuce
India
 Banana
```

Now, you want something like

```
#Hierachical output
Fruit
 France
  Apple
 Vegetable
  Lettuce
India
 Fruit
  Banana
```

In that case, wouldn't this work => `location.subcategories.where(category_id: category.id).each`?

**Edit**:

Perhaps, this could work (in addition to above change):

`<%= category.locations.all(include: sub_categories).each do |location|%>`

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty new to rails, above does print what i need but it is done with a lot of db queries instead of being handled through the :include <-- I'm not entirely sure if what i want to accomplish is possible in this way even...?

Comment: when adding the edit, this is returned:

undefined local variable or method `subcategories' for #<#<Class:0x007f92346015f8>:0x007f923474e050>